# Return type of $ and $$ in webDriverIO

Tags: promise, webdriver-io

we have an automation framework which we migrated from Protractor to webDriverIO.
protractor code uses

```
class ElementWrapper{

    public getAllElement(locator: string){
        return $$(locator)
    }

}
```

we are trying to consume this as below,

```
(await elementWrapperInstance.getAllElement('locator')).filter(async(e)=> {
//function code
})
```

here, we are getting of Javascript filter method getting called and not of ChainablePromiseArray.

we also tried removing the await,

```
(elementWrapperInstance.getAllElement('locator')).filter(async(e)=> {
//function code
})
```

This is resulting in the error filer method not defined.

Can we wrap the $$ in webDriverIO in any other way?

Comment: What is `ChainablePromiseArray`?

Comment: its a return type of $$ in webDriverIO

Comment: Not sure what your issue is, for example the following code is working fine for me:

    const results = (await elementWrapperInstance.getAllElement('locator')).filter(e => e.getText())

and also this:

    results.filter(async e=> await e.getValue() == 'summer')

so I suspect the issue is somewhere in the filter function itself, what is it that you're trying to do in the filter?

Comment: @alkaia, results = (await elementWrapperInstance.getAllElement('locator')).filter(e => e.getText()) ; - In this code, (e=>e.getText()) will run asynchronously, as filter method is from Array of javaScript and not of ChainablePromiseArray. Array.filter does not accept asycn function and does not return the  promise so other iterations run synchronously. Here, I want to ensure the synchronous execution..